# Read write APIs, are they seperate services?

Tags: architecture

I've recently seen System Design examples on GitHub repo system-design-primer, and it shows Read/Write APIs. I'm trying to implement [this](https://github.com/donnemartin/system-design-primer/blob/master/solutions/system_design/pastebin/README.md) one for practice. The outline is like this.
[image]

It separates the read and write APIs, I want to know whether it's just a logical separation or are they separate servers.

Is it good to separate them out if there are a lot more reads than writes? and how would we forward just the read requests to this server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out CQRS - https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html - it seems to hint at that. However, it might be tricky to implement on REST services if you are going for a purist REST approach.

Of course, if you do have significantly more reads that writes, there is a case for separating the API's so that you can scale your read API horizontally.  On the other hand, unless you scale the database as well, you'll still have a single point at which performance issues could manifest.  So while you can add multiple read API's to improve performance, you can probably accomplish the same benefits with a few instances of a caching solution between your service consumers and your API.

And to answer your final question as to how you can direct all read requests to the same server - you can do that routing on a load balancer or API gateway based on the HTTP method (GET, POST, etc.).